# How to create "CONSTRAINT TRIGGER" Postgres on BEFORE event

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Postgres Version: `PostgreSQL 15.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

I read [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) about how to create a `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER`.

and this my query:

```sql
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER my_table_trigger
BEFORE INSERT 
ON my_table
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE FUNCTION my_table_trigger_function();
```

when im run above query, it produce error says:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEFORE"

After looking for solution i found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-createconstraint.html) old documentation. On that doc it says that `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` only support
`AFTER` event. Then i modify my query change `BEFORE` keyword to `AFTER` and query run successfully.

My qestion is did `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` only support `AFTER` event, and did not support `BEFORE` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`CREATE TRIGGERS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtrigger.html)  in version 15 (the current one, which you're using) also says:

> Constraint triggers must be `AFTER ROW` triggers on plain tables (not foreign tables).

It also says (around `BEFORE`, `AFTER`, `INSTEAD OF`):

> A constraint trigger can only be specified as `AFTER`.

So, it doesn't support `BEFORE` triggers.

Comment: Ah, I see. That was my mistake for not reading carefully. Thanks for your help. can i ask another question, why `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` do not support `BEFORE` event ?

Comment: Because they can be deferrable. How can a `BEFORE` trigger be deferrable? What would you expect to be the difference between a trigger and a constraint trigger in a `BEFORE` trigger?

Comment: I can't definitely say, but it generally makes sense. What generally matters about constraints is that the row *as stored* (i.e. after whatever updates may have been made) is consistent. A constraint *before* could lead to false positive if the rest of the logic hasn't updated, and wouldn't necessarily guarantee a correct state after the update.